# How o create sliding div which stops smoothly after time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make sliding element and stop softly after some time. I have used Javascript to add different classes after every 2.5 seconds, but it lags on class change. Is there a better way to make it slow down and stop without lag?

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("banner").classList.add("banner2");
}, "2500");

setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("banner").classList.add("banner3");
}, "5000");

setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("banner").classList.add("banner4");
}, "7500");

setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("banner").classList.add("banner5");
}, "10000");
```

```css
.banner {
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 36px;
  min-width: 5000vw;
  animation: bannermove 25s linear;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.banner2 {
  animation: bannermove 50s linear;
}

.banner3 {
  animation: bannermove 75s linear;
}

.banner4 {
  animation: bannermove 100s linear;
}

.banner5 {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner" class="banner">
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
  <div>Dragon</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div>Charger</div>
  <div>ZipDrive</div>
  <div>LightHouse</div>
  <div>Exxtra</div>
  <div>Hub</div>
  <div>iOS15</div>
  <div>File Drive</div>
  <div>Netherverse</div>
  <div>CLpool</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyframes with multiple percentage values, starting with long periods and then short periods to mimic the desired behavior.
The other solution is not directly related to the question but is another way to handle scrolling to any left position by changing the condition inside setInterval.

```js
  window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  const interval = setInterval(function () {
  if (
    document.getElementById("banner-new").scrollLeft >=
    document.getElementById("banner-new").scrollWidth -
      document.getElementById("banner-new").clientWidth
  ) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  document.getElementById("banner-new").scrollBy({
    behavior: "smooth",
    left: +400,
    top: 0,
  });
}, 2000);
  });
```

```css
.banner-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 36px;
  min-width: 6000vw;
  animation: bannermove 50s linear;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
0% {
transform: translateX(0);
}
20% {
  transform: translateX(-30%);
}
40% {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
60% {
  transform: translateX(-70%);
}
80% {
  transform: translateX(-85%);
}
85% {
  transform: translateX(-90%);
}
90% {
  transform: translateX(-92%);
}
95% {
  transform: translateX(-93%);
}
100% {
  transform: translateX(-94%);
}
}
.banner-new {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 95vw;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.banner-new div {
  margin: 0px 20px;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <div class="banner-container">
        <div id="banner" class="banner">
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
          <div>Dragon</div>
          <div>Element</div>
          <div>Charger</div>
          <div>ZipDrive</div>
          <div>LightHouse</div>
          <div>Exxtra</div>
          <div>Hub</div>
          <div>iOS15</div>
          <div>File Drive</div>
          <div>Netherverse</div>
          <div>CLpool</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>another way</div>

      <div id="banner-new" class="banner-new">
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
        <div>Dragon</div>
        <div>Element</div>
        <div>Charger</div>
        <div>ZipDrive</div>
        <div>LightHouse</div>
        <div>Exxtra</div>
        <div>Hub</div>
        <div>iOS15</div>
        <div>File Drive</div>
        <div>Netherverse</div>
        <div>CLpool</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```